# Charles SSL throttle specific path or url

Tags: throttling, charles-proxy, bandwidth-throttling

I got Charles working, and I know how to use it. I've done throttling before for the entire domain, but I have a need to throttle a specific path or url.

For reference, I can throttle this: `https://www.example.com`

What I want to throttle is: `https://www.example.com/api`

When I enter a `/` in Charles throttle settings it complains about an invalid url, and it doesn't have a field for just "path" like it does for rewrite.

Is it possible to do this? If not, any suggestion on an app I can use to throttle mobile app traffic?

Thanks!